# How to delete part of a string

Tags: php

If I have a string of characters like so:

> This is a test string and I wa

And I wanted to delete everything after the "I" which would also include the space after the I, how would I do this? I definitely need to start at the end of the string and count backwards to the last space but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: What are the exact requirements? What kind of strings do you expect to recieve. What kind of strings do you expect to remove? If it's it's only ever gonna be this exact string and requirements, then theres no point in automating it. If not, then we need some more info about the exact requirements.

Comment: To clarify: is the `I` always gonna be the last `I`, or does it need to be everything from the first occurence of `I`. Is it even always `I` you're looking for? Etc. etc.

Comment: Agreed. The string will change as well as the length. Currently, I have the string length set to 34 characters. What I need is for the last word to get cut off if the word is not complete as in my example above.

Comment: Alright, so to rephrase your requirements, what you really need is an algorithm that cuts a string to a given length at word boundary. Correct?

Comment: If it is correct, then these question will probably have answers you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=truncate+string+word+boundary+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Thanks for the help in explaining this, fire.

Comment: I found the answer fireeyedboy in the link you gave. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove everything after the 'I' by using:

```
$str = 'This is a test string and I wa';
$new_string = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, 'I') + 1);
```

Note: strpos finds the *first* occurrence of the 'I' character.

Comment: Use strrpos to find last occurence if you want that instead.
That will be: `$str = 'This is a test string and I wa'; $new_string = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, 'I') + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Use this to find the last occurence of a character in a string

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

```
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "I");
```

Then substr to split the string

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$newstring = substr($mystring, $pos);
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, I'll have a look there now.

Comment: @Jim, I added the method to split it once you find the location of the "I"

Comment: Thanks Chad. The string will, however be dynamic. I'm not sure I can use strpos for this.

Comment: Oh, I reread your comments and see that your requirements are to cut off incomplete words... not sure how you're going to know that "I want to go with the" is the incomplete sentence of "I want to go with them" though?

Answer (score 0):

You're requirement is not really clear... but

if you want to delete everything after the 'I'

```
$s = 'This is a test string and I wa';
$pos = strpos($s, 'I');
if ($pos !== false)
{
   $s = substr($s, 0, $pos + 1);
}
```

if you want to remove the last space and everything after if

```
$s = 'This is a test string and I wa';
$pos = strrpos($s, ' ');
if ($pos !== false)
{
   $s = substr($s, 0, $pos);
}
```